# Adding bus stops to routes? (Flow, SUMO)

Tags: flow-project

I want to create bus stops (or train stops). How can I do this in flow?

SUMO has this Option: https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Simulation/Public_Transport, but routes do not seem to have this option (in Flow).

I tried adding them nevertheless to the routes.
I read some scenarios, but none of them use stops (or anything besides regular routes)
...trying to add bus stops to the source code now, but I hope there is a better solution

```
def specify_routes(self, net_params):
    rts = {
           "a": ["a"],
           "b": ["b"],
           "fix_route": ["a"]
           # This does not work, obviously
           #,"stop": ["lane": "a", "endPos": 50, "duration": 20]
           }

    return rts
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your great suggestion.

Flow currently does not support these. We just opened an issue to (hopefully) add this as a new feature to the Flow.

Here is the link: https://github.com/flow-project/flow/issues/712

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and addressing this problem! :) Also fyi, I have now simulated a bus stop with a very lowspeed edge. This also gives kind of information how long the vehicle will still be "waiting" there.

Answer (score -2):

A great question. Yes, we need more flexibility when using FLOW. he examples given by FLOW basically built the sumo files and does not give us too much options. It would be great if we can directly use the net, route, and cfg files created by SUMO, and use the DRL algorithms directly. I am not sure though, may we are already able to do so?